# How to use GetExtentOfWord in the new IAsyncQuickInfoSource API?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a C# extension for Visual Studio and I am trying to use the new API for QuickInfos: https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-editor-api/wiki/Modern-Quick-Info-API. I am prototyping based on this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncQuickInfo. It works fine as long as I don't change it.

The sample is only focusing on the whole line:

```
var line = triggerPoint.Value.GetContainingLine();
```

However, I need to get the hovered **word**. In the old API, I was using this and it was working fine:

```
var navigator = provider.NavigatorService.GetTextStructureNavigator(buffer);
var hoveredWord = navigator.GetExtentOfWord(triggerPoint.Value);
```

Unfortunately, **Visual Studio will freeze** as soon as I call GetExtentOfWord with the new API!!! More precisely, I will pass a few times and then it will freeze (quite shortly).

What should do I to be allowed to get the hovered word extent with the new IAsyncQuickInfoSource API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us to test this issue? Besides, when you call this codes, did it face any errors? Or did you use Watch Window to monitor these variables? Any detailed info will help us troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Hi Perry! Thanks for your reply. As stated in my question, I am using the sample from Microsoft VSSDK here: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncQuickInfo: this is a minimal, reproducible example. You can easily reproduce by getting the sample, and add a call to the 2 lines I mention (GetTextStructureNavigator and GetExtentOfWord). And I don't face any error: the IDE will just freeze. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I could set a breakpoint just after calling GetExtentOfWord and use the Watch window. It will work for a variable number of times: breaking correctly, displaying the content of the hovered word, restarting gracefully when I hit F5. However, it will always end up freezing and I never get a single exception nor error message. What do you mean by using "log format to check it"? Can you be more specific, please? Thanks.